# Qt Not Recognizing Qt/3D Libraries

Tags: qt, 3d

Qt is not recognizing the Qt/3d i am using. I have QT Creator 4.7, and do not know if the problem is something i should include in my .pro file. I have QT += opengl already. Some of what I am trying to #include are: QGLView, QGLBuilder, and QGLCube.

Answer (score 1):

[QGLView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt3d-snapshot/qglview.html), [QGLBuilder](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt3d-snapshot/qglbuilder.html), [QGLCube](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt3d-snapshot/qglcube.html) are introduced in QT 4.8. You need to update your QT library.